# How to query for a document with a reference path?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm querying for some songs in my Songs collection, so I can send the song data to a third-party in an http request. Before I send the song, I need the name of the song's Artist. I have a separate Artists collection, where each Artist document has a "name" field. I need to send the Artist name with the rest of my song's data.

I can't seem to find any documentation for the **Firebase Admin SDK** that eludes to getting a document strictly with a reference path as a field.

```
exports.songs = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
db.collection('songs')
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            let data = doc.data()
            let artist = data.artist // reference field to artist document?
            artist.get().then(documentSnapshot => {
            response.send(documentSnapshot)
            })
        })
        })
     .catch(error => {
     console.log('Error getting documents: ', error)
     })
 })
```

I'm expecting to receive `doc.data()` of the referenced artist document. However, I'm just getting timed out.

Comment: So all you want to do is query for a single document using a reference type value with a unique value, and you know the full reference path ahead of time?

Comment: What is `data.artist`? Is it a string? If yes, what you need to do is: `db.collection('artisList').doc(data.artist).get()...` instead of `artist.get()`

Comment: @DougStevenson `song.artist` is a reference to an `artist` document in my `artists` collection. So I do have the full reference path ahead of time. What I don't know, and please forgive me for not being as clear in my question, is how to use that reference field to query for the referenced artist. Also, thanks for taking time out of your Sunday evening to read my question. I really appreciate it.
'
@TonyBui `data.artist` is a reference type field.

Answer (score 1):

You can query on reference type fields just like any other field.  All you have to do is pass in a DocumentReference type object:

```
const artistRef = db.collection("artists").child("some-artist-id");

db
    .collection("songs")
    .where("artist", "==", artistRef)
    .get()
    .then(...)
```

Comment: But how do I get "some-artist-id" from my song's artist reference field?

Shouldn't I be able to do something like this?
    db.collection('artists')
    .where(id, '==', song.artist)

Comment: I thought you said you knew the reference "ahead of time".  It sounds like you don't.  If you don't know the full path of the reference, you're not going to be able to do this, and I'm not sure how exactly you expect to be able to locate a unique thing without knowing its full unique value.

Comment: I guess I thought that if I query a document that contains a reference field to another document, doesn't that mean I "know" the path to it? After all, in my song document I have a reference field called artist which contains "artist/123456". Doesn't that point to my artist? And now that I've quered my song, I should be able to access that reference field and also query the artist with it?

Comment: So you want to fetch the ENTRE collection to get one document? That's massively inefficient at scale, and expensive.

Comment: Good point, I don't want to fetch the entire artists collection just to get one artist document. However, I do need to fetch my entire songs collection, iterate through it to find all rock songs (easy). Then, for each rock song I find, I want to go ahead and fetch the artist's name using the reference field in my song document.

Comment: That kinda sounds like a different problem than the one you originally proposed.